# how to use angular for rendering the views in express

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I wish to use angular for rendering the output page. What are all the changes to be done in the default Express files. What should be used in the part of

```
          app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

Comment: Hello Nivash-Iot, welcome to SO. Your question seems to be way too broad to find an answer here. You must show you did something on your own, not just asking people to do your work. So start trying doing it, then specific problems will appear and you will start raising answerable questions!

Comment: Thanks for spending your time for the response. Actually iam very new to programming and iam learning programming myself. I have learnt almost all the concepts in nodejs now iam writing my first full project. But here raises the bigger(more silly) doubts. I cant move ahead of my project without knowing this. That is the reason why i posted here iam sure that this will be doubts of many beginners.

Comment: I think you need to go with some MEAN Stack tutorial first. that will help you here is some link  https://github.com/cornflourblue/mean-stack-registration-login-example       https://github.com/michaelcheng429/meanstacktutorial

Comment: Thanks @Shubam Batra your tutorial links helped me a lot....

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: None. It's a client side library.

You don't have to modify the server side code, just add Angular's JavaScript file to your Jade template and start using the additions.

Comment: Actually i dint study jade. Is it a must i should study jade for proceeding with express or any-other server side templating engine.

Comment: No, but try it. It makes writing documents a lot easier, since you really just write down the outline/structure using indentation rather then closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

Jade creates html template rendered in browser on the server side .You can include angular.js on jade template . Something like

```
doctype html
html(ng-app='app-name')
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js')
    script(src='javascripts/next-update-stats.js')
```

Node.js server

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```